# Wii controller mysteriously shut down when setting up the console

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii

I bought the *Power Ranger* Wii game to play.  I put the game in just as I do the other games and proceeded to go thru the steps of setting up the game to play.  It said to hook up the nunchucks and then my Wii controller shut down.   What is wrong with my game?

Comment: Have you checked the batteries in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Wii remote will lose its sync with the Wii, particularly if it has recently lost all power, or if the machine itself has been unplugged.

If you've made it as far as starting up the game though, this is probably not the problem, but if the remote flashes and then goes dark when you press a button, then it has, for some reason, lost sync with your game, and you will need to re-sync it.

Take the casing off the back of the remote, making sure you have a set of batteries inside of it, and press the red sync button, then hold down the red sync button on the Wii, beneath the little flap next to the CD port, to sync your remote.

If this does not work, or your wiimote is not flashing when you press one of the regular input buttons, then your remote's batteries are dead, and you will need to replace them/recharge the wiimote.

Answer (score 0):

You may have put on the parental controls on that specific game or when you hooked up the nun-chunks it had a bad connection and the controller froze up.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this too, and reconnecting the batteries worked for me